# Selecting dynamically created models within a collection

Tags: backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I have a set of "Person name" inputs with the class `person` that I'm trying to do the following with: each time a keyup is recorded in the input, grab that input's data-hash attribute, and if there's not already an instance of Person with that hash in the collection People, add a model. Otherwise just update the model where hash matches.

```
$('.person').keyup(function(){

var myHash = $(this).attr('data-hash'),
 myName = $(this).val(),
 checkMe = people.where({'hash':myHash});

if ( checkMe.length > 0 ){

//update name value where hash matches

}

else {
 people.add({
   'name':myName,
   'hash':myHash
  });
}
});
```

Instead of using `var person = new Person` I'm adding these models to the collection using Backbone's `add` method.

So now I have a number of elements when I call `people.models` but I can't figure out how to select them. Normally you'd say `person.get('attribute')` but I'm not sure how to select the model if it has no `var` name. What could I put in the code instead of `//update name value where hash matches`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

checkMe should be an array of models you're trying to update. Iterate through them and use the set method:

```
$('.person').keyup(function(){

var myHash = $(this).attr('data-hash'),
 myName = $(this).val(),
 checkMe = people.where({'hash':myHash});

if ( checkMe.length > 0 ){
  _.each(checkMe, function(person){
    person.set({
      'name':myName,
    });
  });
}

else {
 people.add({
   'name':myName,
   'hash':myHash
  });
}
});
```